# group_by not working correctly, only part of variable selected for grouping

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm trying to calculate the rate of change of particular variable, `gstatus`, but `group_by` is only selecting three characters in the middle of my ID variable `RAUMID` to group. Here's a brief sample of my dataframe:

```
> head(df_long, 20)
    RAUMID gcode       tg1      tg2      tg3      tg4      tg5 is_eg F_IN_KRAFT.x Year gstatus
1  1011101     4  8.000000 4.000000 1.998631 0.000000 0.000000     0            0 2003       0
2  1011102     3  1.998631 4.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000     0            0 2003       0
3  1011103     3  9.998631 2.001369 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000     1         2019 2003       0
4  1011104     5  4.000000 4.000000 4.000000 1.998631 1.002053     0            0 2003       0
5  1011105     3  1.998631 4.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000     0            0 2003       0
6  1011201     4  4.000000 4.000000 1.998631 0.000000 0.000000     0            0 2003       0
7  1011202     3  4.000000 4.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000     0            0 2003       0
8  1011203     3  1.998631 6.001369 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000     0            0 2003       0
9  1011204     4  4.000000 4.000000 1.998631 0.000000 0.000000     0            0 2003       0
10 1011301     3  9.998631 2.001369 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000     0            0 2003       0
11 1011302     1  0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000     0            0 2003       0
12 1011303     1  0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000     1         2019 2003       0
13 1011304     4  4.000000 6.001369 5.998631 0.000000 0.000000     0            0 2003       1
14 1011305     5  8.000000 2.001369 1.998631 2.001369 3.000684     0            0 2003       1
15 1011306     4  4.000000 6.001369 4.000000 0.000000 0.000000     0            0 2003       1
16 1011401     4  1.998631 4.000000 4.000000 0.000000 0.000000     0            0 2003       0
17 1011402     3  5.998631 2.001369 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000     0            0 2003       0
18 1022101     3  4.000000 6.001369 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000     0            0 2003       1
19 1022102     4  4.000000 6.001369 1.998631 0.000000 0.000000     0            0 2003       1
20 1022103     2 10.001369 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000     0            0 2003       1
```

And here's what happens when I try using `dplyr::group_by()`:

```
> df_long %>% group_by(RAUMID)
# A tibble: 4,023 x 11
# Groups:   RAUMID [447]
    RAUMID gcode   tg1   tg2   tg3   tg4   tg5 is_eg F_IN_KRAFT.x  Year gstatus
     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 1011101     4  8     4     2.00  0     0        0            0  2003       0
 2 1011102     3  2.00  4     0     0     0        0            0  2003       0
 3 1011103     3 10.0   2.00  0     0     0        1         2019  2003       0
 4 1011104     5  4     4     4     2.00  1.00     0            0  2003       0
 5 1011105     3  2.00  4     0     0     0        0            0  2003       0
 6 1011201     4  4     4     2.00  0     0        0            0  2003       0
 7 1011202     3  4     4     0     0     0        0            0  2003       0
 8 1011203     3  2.00  6.00  0     0     0        0            0  2003       0
 9 1011204     4  4     4     2.00  0     0        0            0  2003       0
10 1011301     3 10.0   2.00  0     0     0        0            0  2003       0
# … with 4,013 more rows
```

While not shown in the copy-paste, digits 2-4 are underlined in my console. Additionally, the row is of class `factor`, and, interestingly, in `View(df_long)`, I'm able to order the row `RAUMID` and it is successfully grouped.

Edit: to be clear, I know that the data isn't grouped correctly because of what I said above regarding viewing, and because using `test <- df_long[order(df_long$RAUMID),]`, it works correctly.

```
> head(test)
      RAUMID gcode tg1 tg2      tg3 tg4 tg5 is_eg F_IN_KRAFT.x Year gstatus
1    1011101     4   8   4 1.998631   0   0     0            0 2003       0
448  1011101     4   8   4 1.998631   0   0     0            0 2005       1
895  1011101     4   8   4 1.998631   0   0     0            0 2007       1
1342 1011101     4   8   4 1.998631   0   0     0            0 2009       1
1789 1011101     4   8   4 1.998631   0   0     0            0 2011       1
2236 1011101     4   8   4 1.998631   0   0     0            0 2013       2
```

Comment: It shows RAUMID as `dbl` instead of `factor`

Comment: It is not clear from your example about the issue

Comment: Why are you assuming the grouping is only using the middle 3 digits? Just looking at the first couple of rows, the grouping is being done using the entire `RAUMID` value.

Comment: Perhaps you are just confused that group_by is changing your data.frame into a tibble which prints differently. Also just doing a group_by on it's own doesn't really change anything. I'm not sure what you expect to change.

Comment: see edits I just made

Comment: Akrun and MrFlick, could you elaborate on why it is a dbl? I'm confused as to what's happening, as when I call `class(df_long)$RAUMID`, the result is `factor`

Comment: well, `class(df_long)$RAUMID` shouldn't work, do you mean `class(df_long$RAUMID)`? A `group_by` statement only adds metadata to your tibble. It does not change the row order or anything. If what's what you want, use `dplyr::arrange`. Using `group_by` will only affect the behavior of other dplyr verbs. It will not change how you work with the table using base R syntax.

Comment: Yes, `class(df_long$RAUMID)` is what I meant. Thanks for explaining this — I think I understand now that I need to use some aggregating function afterwards. I was trying to use this to feed into a function that creates panel data that wasn't working.